# How to insert items at a certain position in a recyclerView?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have set up a `fragment` with a `recyclerView` in it and I fetch data from `firestore` successfully. What I want to know is that if it is possible to add items at a certain position in recyclerView. Suppose, I want to add an item (from a different collection in Firestore) after every 5 items in a recyclervView. Is it possible to do it in Android using Kotlin?

Thank you.

Edit:

`DashboardFragment.kt`

```
class DashboardFragment : BaseFragment() {

    var srchProductsList: ArrayList<Product> = ArrayList()
    var adList: ArrayList<Ads> = ArrayList()
    var srchTempProductsList: ArrayList<Product> = ArrayList()
    var newView: String = "ListView"

    private lateinit var binding: FragmentDashboardBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)

    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        binding = FragmentDashboardBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        binding.fbDashboard.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_grid_view)
        binding.fbDashboard.setOnClickListener {

            if (newView=="ListView"){
                newView="GridView"
                fb_dashboard.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_list_view)
            }else{
                newView="ListView"
                fb_dashboard.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_grid_view)
            }

            onResume()

        }
        return binding.root
    }

  override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        val id = item.itemId

        when (id) {

            R.id.action_settings -> {

                startActivity(Intent(activity, SettingsActivity::class.java))
                return true
            }

            R.id.action_cart -> {
                startActivity(Intent(activity, CartListActivity::class.java))
                return true
            }
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()

     srchProductsList.clear()
        srchTempProductsList.clear()
        getDashboardItemsList()
    }

    private fun getDashboardItemsList() {
       
        showProgressDialog(resources.getString(R.string.please_wait))

        getDashboardItemsList2()
    }


   fun successDashboardItemsList(dashboardItemsList: ArrayList<Product>) {

        val adsLists =getListOfAds()

        hideProgressDialog()

        if (dashboardItemsList.size > 0) {
            Toast.makeText(
                context,
                "Total " + dashboardItemsList.size + " products loaded",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
            ).show()
            rv_dashboard_items.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            tv_no_dashboard_items_found.visibility = View.GONE

            rv_dashboard_items.layoutManager =
                StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL)
            rv_dashboard_items.setHasFixedSize(true)

            val adapter = DashboardItemsListAdapterTest(requireActivity(), dashboardItemsList,adsLists)
            rv_dashboard_items.adapter = adapter

//////// I HAVE PROBLEM WITH THE FOLLOWING BLOCK OF CODE WHICH IS WHY I HAVE COMMENTED IT OUT ONLY TO CHECK IF OTHER PART OF THE CODE IS WORKING. I NEED TO FIX THE ERROR FOR THE BELOW BLOCK OF CODE ALSO

/*            adapter.setOnClickListener(object :
                DashboardItemsListAdapter.OnClickListener {
                override fun onClick(position: Int, product: Product) {

                    val intent = Intent(context, ProductDetailsActivity::class.java)
                    intent.putExtra(Constants.EXTRA_PRODUCT_ID, product.product_id)
                    intent.putExtra(Constants.EXTRA_PRODUCT_OWNER_ID, product.user_id)
                    startActivity(intent)
                }
            })*/
            
        } else {
            rv_dashboard_items.visibility = View.GONE
            tv_no_dashboard_items_found.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }

    }


    fun successDashboardItemsListListView(dashboardItemsList: ArrayList<Product>) {

        val adsLists =getListOfAds()

        hideProgressDialog()

        if (dashboardItemsList.size > 0) {
            Toast.makeText(
                context,
                "Total " + dashboardItemsList.size + " products loaded",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
            ).show()
            rv_dashboard_items.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            tv_no_dashboard_items_found.visibility = View.GONE

            rv_dashboard_items.layoutManager =
                LinearLayoutManager(context)
            rv_dashboard_items.setHasFixedSize(true)

            val adapter = DashboardItemsListAdapterTest(requireActivity(), dashboardItemsList,adsLists)
            rv_dashboard_items.adapter = adapter

//////// I HAVE PROBLEM WITH THE FOLLOWING BLOCK OF CODE WHICH IS WHY I HAVE COMMENTED IT OUT ONLY TO CHECK IF OTHER PART OF THE CODE IS WORKING. I NEED TO FIX THE ERROR FOR THE BELOW BLOCK OF CODE ALSO

/*            adapter.setOnClickListener(object :
                DashboardItemsListAdapter.OnClickListener {
                override fun onClick(position: Int, product: Product) {

                    val intent = Intent(context, ProductDetailsActivity::class.java)
                    intent.putExtra(Constants.EXTRA_PRODUCT_ID, product.product_id)
                    intent.putExtra(Constants.EXTRA_PRODUCT_OWNER_ID, product.user_id)
                    startActivity(intent)
                }
            })*/
            
        } else {
            rv_dashboard_items.visibility = View.GONE
            tv_no_dashboard_items_found.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.dashboard_menu, menu)
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)

        val item = menu.findItem(R.id.my_search_bar)
        val searchView = item?.actionView as SearchView
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {

            override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
                srchTempProductsList.clear()
                val searchKey = query
                if (searchKey != null) {
                    if (searchKey.isNotEmpty()) {
                        srchProductsList.forEach {
                            if (it.description.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
                                    .contains(searchKey)
                            ) {
                                srchTempProductsList.add(it)
                            }
                        }
                        rv_dashboard_items.adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()

                    } else {
                        srchTempProductsList.clear()
                        srchTempProductsList.addAll(srchProductsList)
                        rv_dashboard_items.adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()

                    }
                }

                return false

            }

            override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {

                srchTempProductsList.clear()
                val searchText = newText!!.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())

                if (searchText.isNotEmpty()) {
                    srchProductsList.forEach {
                        if (it.description.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(searchText)) {
                            srchTempProductsList.add(it)
                        }
                    }
                    rv_dashboard_items.adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()

                } else {
                    srchTempProductsList.clear()
                    srchTempProductsList.addAll(srchProductsList)
                    rv_dashboard_items.adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()

                }

                return false

            }

        })

    }

    private fun getDashboardItemsList2() {
        val mFireStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
       
        mFireStore.collection(Constants.PRODUCTS)
            .get() 
            .addOnSuccessListener { document ->

                for (i in document.documents) {

                    val product = i.toObject(Product::class.java)!!
                    product.product_id = i.id
                    srchProductsList.add(product)

                }
                srchTempProductsList.addAll(srchProductsList)

                if (newView == "ListView") {
                    successDashboardItemsListListView(srchTempProductsList)
                } else {
                    successDashboardItemsList(srchTempProductsList)
                }
            }
            .addOnFailureListener {

            }
    }


    private fun getListOfAds() : ArrayList<Ads>{
        val mFireStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
       
        mFireStore.collection("ads")
            .get() 
            .addOnSuccessListener { document ->

                for (i in document.documents) {

                    val ad = i.toObject(Ads::class.java)!!
                    ad.ad_id = i.id
                    adList.add(ad)

                }

            }
            .addOnFailureListener {

            }
        return adList
    }

}
```

`DashboardItemListAdapterTest.kt`

```
open class DashboardItemsListAdapterTest(
    private val context: Context,
    private var prodlist: ArrayList<Product>,
    private var adslist: ArrayList<Ads>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

    companion object {
        const val produc= 1
        const val ads= 2
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        return if (viewType == produc) {
            val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.item_dashboard_list_view_layout, parent, false)
            Collection1Holder(view)
        } else {
            val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.item_dashboard_ad_view_layout, parent, false)
            Collection2Holder(view)
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val promodel = prodlist[position]
        val adsmodel = adslist[position]
        if(getItemViewType(position) == produc) {
            holder.itemView.tv_item_name.text = promodel.title
        }else{
            holder.itemView.tv_item_name.text = adsmodel.title
        }

    }


    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return prodlist.size + adslist.size
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return if(position%5 == 0) ads else produc
    }


    inner class Collection1Holder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    }

    inner class Collection2Holder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    }
}
```

Model class
`Ads.kt`

```
data class Ads(
    val title: String = "",
    var ad_id: String = ""
)
```

Comment: This can be done in couple of ways. You can combine your item layout with all views of secondary layout gone. In onBindViewHolder, check if position % 5 == 0, then make all secondary views visible and fill data to them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two viewholder for two different collections of data.

Change your adapter class like this.

```
class YourAdapter() : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

    companion object {
        const val COLLCTION1= 1
        const val COLLCTION2= 2
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        return if (viewType == COLLCTION1) {
            val view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.collection1, viewGroup, false)
            Collection1Holder(view)
        } else {
            val view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.collection2, viewGroup, false)
            Collection2Holder(view)
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        if(getItemViewType(position) == COLLCTION1) {
            holder.name.text = collection1.text
        }else{
            holder.name.text = collection2.text
        }

    }


    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            return collection1.size + collection2.size
       }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return if(position%5 == 0) COLLCTION2 else COLLCTION1
    }
    
    
    inner class Collection1Holder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    
        }
    
    inner class Collection2Holder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you tell me what are COLLCTION1= 1, COLLCTION2= 2, collection1 and collection2? Is there a typo within the companion object where both are 'COLLCTION1'. Thank you.

Comment: yes, that was a typo 2nd one will be Collection2. Actually, I have used collection1, collection2 just as dummy names. Because I don't know your class name or collection name. You can change it to whatever you like or whatever name suits your app. In companion object, those two are const values that's why I have capitalized them.

Comment: I try to change my code, but I do not know if this is how I am supposed to change it. Logcat is added to my question.

Comment: This is the line of code 'val adsmodel = adslist[position]' which logcat is pointing at - (DashboardItemsListAdapterTest.kt:38)

Comment: Your adlist is empty. That's why adslist[position] returns IndexOutOfBoundsException. Check if there is data in your adlist List. It's better if you attach the code.

Comment: Code added to the question.

Comment: Use log adlist.toString() or toast to check if data is retrieving successfully from firestore.